# Debian IPv6 DHCP not working when rebooting

Tags: debian, dhcp, ipv6

For some reason I won't get an IPv6 address when rebooting my Debian 8 System, while I get one when restarting the networking service. The DHCPv6 server is up and running (and is answering when using dhclient or restarting the networking service).

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet6 loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet6 dhcp
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

What do I have to configure to get an address when booting?

Comment: Is there anything in the logs?  Does the IPv6 DHCP client process actually start?

Comment: @Zoredache can you give me a hint where to look?

Comment: I would start looking in the `/var/log/syslog` I believe the dhcp client normally logs there.

Comment: @Zoredache http://pastebin.com/BbxqubGX is what I get with "cat /var/log/syslog | grep dhclient" after a reboot, http://pastebin.com/EbpAMSKG is the result of a "service networking restart". As explained in the question, the ipv6 was only assigned after restarting the networking service again. It's a fresh install. DHCP Server logs: after reboot http://pastebin.com/FimTugYs, after networking restart http://pastebin.com/Jr6tLUWW

Comment: I am not seeing the IPv6 assignment in your DHCP logs.  Just out of curiosity, are you sure you are getting DHCP at all, and not just using a stateless address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is apparently a bit of a timing bug present.  I believe I have replicated your problem in a VM and fixed it by adjusting the config.

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet6 dhcp
    pre-up sleep 3
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Ref Links

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/1447715
- https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2015/05/msg00235.html

Comment: Had to use post-up sleep for the IPv4 interface to get it work. Thanks for pointing out the bug